# How would you maintain the vlrs value of xyz point cloud file while converting it to las and then finally to COPC

Tags: las, xyz, pdal, laspy

I am trying to convert the point cloud files that I have to COPC and starting with converting all files that we have( currently xyz) to las and then proceed to COPC conversion from las using PDAL, while converting an xyz file to las I am losing the VLRS value. Below is the code i am using for the conversion from xyz to las, Any help on how I can get or retain the VLRS value of my xyz file to the converted las file

> ```
> def _translate_xyz_to_las(self, buffer):
> ```

```
    with BytesIO(buffer) as bytesio:
        file_path = self.output_file_path 

        df = pd.read_csv(bytesio, sep=",", header=None, engine='pyarrow')

        header = laspy.LasHeader(point_format=7, version="1.2")
        header.offsets = np.min(df.values[:, :3], axis=0)
        header.scales = np.array([.1, .1, .1])

        las = laspy.LasData(header)
        las.xyz = df.values[:, :3]
        las.red = df.iloc[:, 3].values
        las.green = df.iloc[:, 4].values
        las.blue = df.iloc[:, 5].values
        las_file_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + '.las'
        las.write(las_file_path)

        return las_file_path
```

> Blockquote